# How can I pass the name of a tableview cell to another swift file without using segues?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

**More Details:**

I would like to replace the `customerLabel` with the value of the cell selected in a table found in a different ViewController.

The following is the View Controller (`FeedDetail`) I would like the value to go (replacing `customerLabel`)

```
class FeedDetail: UIViewController, URLSessionDataDelegate {


    weak var delegate: FeedDetailProtocol!

    func downloadItems() {
        let customerLabel = "CustomerName"
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.example.com/sample/sample.php")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "a=\(customerLabel)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            print("response = \(response)")

            if let data = data, let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("responseString = \(responseString)")
                print(self.theTitle)
                self.parseJSON(data)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

This is the table with the value I would like to share with the first controller, The variable `titleStr` is what needs to passed to `FeedDetail`.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Retrieve cell
    let cellIdentifier: String = "stockCell"
    let myCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)!
    myCell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    myCell.textLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
    // Get the stock to be shown
    let item: StockModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! StockModel
    // Configure our cell title made up of name and price


    let titleStr = [item.customer].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: "-")


    print(titleStr)
    // Get references to labels of cell
    myCell.textLabel!.text = titleStr

    return myCell
}
```

---

**Update 2:**

This ViewController (`showCustomerDetails`) is what opens when a table cell is selected, the data comes from `FeedDetail` (includes FeedDetailProtocol):

```
import UIKit

class showCustomerDetails: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, FeedDetailProtocol  {


    @IBOutlet weak var navButton: UIButton!

    var detectionString : String!
    var feedItems: NSArray = NSArray()
    var selectedStock : DetailModel = DetailModel()


    @IBOutlet weak var cancelButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var stockResultsFeed: UITableView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let vc = FeedDetail()



        self.stockResultsFeed.delegate = self
        self.stockResultsFeed.dataSource = self

        let detailModel = FeedDetail()
        detailModel.delegate = self
        detailModel.downloadItems()

    }
```

Comment: Can you explain more?

Comment: How are you even extending protocol, what is the class ? Please add some more code!

Comment: I have added more details, my approach has changed slightly, I think its more logical to take the variable of the table view cell, and pass it to FeedDetail for it to replace the value of  customerLabel

Comment: @RajeshKumarR please let me know if you have any questions

Comment: FeedDetail opens when you select a cell right?

Comment: @RelsonJames how are you showing FeedDetail when a table view cell is selected?

Comment: It's a bit different than that actually, showCustomerDetails opens when a cell is selected, which gets its data from FeedDetail

Comment: So you have a first view controller with a table view containing "`StockModel` backed" cells when one of which is selected, the view controller `showCustomerDetails` is opened via a segue and the `FeedDetail` view controller is initialized in the `viewDidLoad` as a result. Does that sound right?

Comment: @Callam Yes that is correct!

Comment: You need to intercept the segue that is performed when the stock cell is selected - this can be done with `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue...`. You cast the `segue.destination` to a `showCustomerDetails`

Comment: Can you please show an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the solutions provided above. You could make use of UserDefaults. In your **didSelectRowAt** method set a user default value like

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("The title", forKey: "Your key")
```

Then in your next vc when ever you want to use the title you selected before, retrieve it using

```
UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: “Your Key")
```

Comment: What goes in the for key field?

Comment: Your response looks interesting, what can be put in key to pass the following value`let titleStr = [item.customer].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: "-")`

Comment: Can you please show an example I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Key is simply a unique identifier for your set value in userdefaults. I have edited my response for clarification. So in your case it could be "titleKey" or anything you find suitable. Just make sure you are using the same key in oher activity while retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable `theTitle` in your secondViewController

```
var theTitle:String?
```

and in your firstViewController use the below code

```
let vc = MySecondViewController()
vc.theTitle = "\(navigationItem.title)"
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: I don't want the second navigation controller to be pushed when opening. All I need is to create a variable with the current title in the navigation controller. And have this variable avaliable in my second view controller

Answer (score 0):

Use the **title** property of `UIViewController`

```
let vc = ViewController1()
vc.title = "Test"
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

**Test** would be displayed on `ViewController1`'s navigation title.
If you saying you don't want the second ViewController to be pushed, it is not possible unless you take 1) Application variable. Or what you might do is call the first two lines and then call the third line whenever you need so. But, *don't re-initialize* `ViewController1`, else the **title** will be lost.

Comment: Please have another look at my update, I think this other approach could be better. Taking the value of the selected cell and passing it to the other file

Answer (score 0):

In FeedDetail class create a string variable

```
var strTitle = ""
```

In the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of first viewcontroller write this code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let vc = FeedDetail()..let item: StockModel = feedItems[indexPath.row] as! StockModel
    let titleStr = [item.customer].compactMap { $0 }.joined(separator: "-")
    vc.strTitle = titleStr
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Nothing seems to be passed to FeedDetail

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use segue, you could use `NotificationCenter` which you could use to emit events from your cell and listner to them in your second viewcontroller.

> A notification dispatch mechanism that enables the broadcast of
>   information to registered observers.

To emit events, add this inside your `cellForRowAt`:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("YOURKEY"), object: nil, userInfo: ["titleKey": titleStr])
```

Then you should subscribe to this event by adding a listener inside your second view controller (the event will be emitted by the cell in your case):

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.myFunc(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("YOURKEY"), object: nil)
```

Then add the function that will be execute when you receive an event (from your cell):

```
 @objc func myFunc(notification: Notification) {

        guard let data = notification.userInfo as? [String: String] else {
            return
        }
        debugPrint("my title \(data["titleKey"])")

    }
```

Comment: Can you show me an example of how you would use it with the value of titleStr in cellForRowAt.

Answer (score 0):

Add a computed property to the `StockModel` class that puts together the `titleStr`.

```
extension StockModel {
    var titleStr: String {
        return [customer].compactMap({ $0 }).joined(separator: "-")
    }
}
```

You can use this while dequeuing the cell:

```
myCell.textLabel!.text = item.titleStr
```

Inside your first view controller, the one showing a table view of `StockModel` cells, you can prepare the destination view controller (`showCustomerDetails`) when a cell is selected. The inherited method we're overriding below provides you with the segue (giving you the destination controller) and the sender of the segue. The prototype cell in the storyboard is connected to the `showCustomerDetails` controller segue, so the sender in this scenario would be the `UITableViewCell` that was selected.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch (segue.destination, sender) {
    case (let controller as showCustomerDetails, let cell as UITableViewCell):
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
            controller.selectedStock = feedItems[indexPath.row] as? StockModel
        }
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

In your `showCustomerDetail` view controller, I have presumed that the `selectedStock` property is supposed to be a `StockModel`, and not a `DetailModel`. In which case, you can use the `customer` property of the `selectedStock` to download the items pertaining to that customer.

```
func downloadItems(customerLabel: String)
```

Make this adjustment to the function so you can pass in the `titleStr`. In the `viewDidLoad` method of `showCustomerDetails`, using `selectedStock` assuming it is of type `StockModel`, you can get the `customerLabel` needed to download the items with the `titleStr` property.

```
detailModel.downloadItems(customerLabel: selectedStock.titleStr)
```

Comment: @Relson James are my presumptions about the `selectedStock` property correct?